# Unit testing Spring MVC Controller: java.util.Map data not bound

Tags: spring, unit-testing, spring-mvc, controller, mockito

Dear devs at stackoverflow,

I would really appreciate your help with a tricky problem I am not able to resolve while unit testing one of my Spring MVC controllers.

The entire code repository can be found here: https://github.com/peerpub/peerpub

**Environment:**

- Java 8
- Maven 3.5
- Spring Boot 2.0.1
- Spring Framework 5.0.4
- Thymeleaf 3
- JUnit 5 + Mockito

**Problem description:**

While trying to come up with detailed tests for [`DocTypeAdminCtrl.java`](https://github.com/peerpub/peerpub/blob/oliver_dtsvc/src/main/java/de/fzj/peerpub/doc/doctype/DocTypeAdminCtrl.java) using a unit test approach with Mockito/MockMVC, I am not able to bind data based on a `Map`, while simple `String` and `Boolean` work just fine. The same is happening when I try to use this in my full-stack integration tests (already tried that).

*While using the application via the web browser, this problem does not appear, so this seems to be entirely testing related.*

All tests named `editPost...()` in [`DocTypeAdminCtrlTest.java`](https://github.com/peerpub/peerpub/blob/oliver_dtsvc/src/test/java/de/fzj/peerpub/doc/doctype/DocTypeAdminCtrlTest.java) fail. Example log excerpt from `mvn test`:

```
Tests run: 7, Failures: 3, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.437 sec <<< FAILURE! - in de.fzj.peerpub.doc.doctype.DocTypeAdminCtrlTest
editPostFormSuccess  Time elapsed: 0.103 sec  <<< FAILURE!
java.lang.AssertionError: Status expected:<302> but was:<200>
at de.fzj.peerpub.doc.doctype.DocTypeAdminCtrlTest.editPostFormSuccess(DocTypeAdminCtrlTest.java:148)

editPostFormNonMatchingNames  Time elapsed: 0.046 sec  <<< FAILURE!
java.lang.AssertionError: Model attribute 'doctype' expected:   <DocTypeForm(name=vfAtXQ, displayName=01p14G7v22, system=false, multiDoc=true, attributes=[6Vuzhn, zKXSTl], mandatory={6Vuzhn=null, zKXSTl=true}, defaults={6Vuzhn=, zKXSTl=sooeOYb6Ld})> but was:<DocTypeForm(name=vfAtXQ, displayName=01p14G7v22, system=false, multiDoc=true, attributes=[6Vuzhn, zKXSTl], mandatory=null, defaults=null)>
at de.fzj.peerpub.doc.doctype.DocTypeAdminCtrlTest.editPostFormNonMatchingNames(DocTypeAdminCtrlTest.java:165)

editPostFormExceptionDTO  Time elapsed: 0.041 sec  <<< FAILURE!
java.lang.AssertionError: Model attribute 'doctype' expected:<DocTypeForm(name=GPzldO, displayName=mIV7Utta1Y, system=false, multiDoc=false, attributes=[8GsYhQ, bZGkd2], mandatory={8GsYhQ=null, bZGkd2=true}, defaults={8GsYhQ=SfoDlEiYAz, bZGkd2=k4uaLxx8yf})> but was:<DocTypeForm(name=GPzldO, displayName=mIV7Utta1Y, system=false, multiDoc=false, attributes=[8GsYhQ, bZGkd2], mandatory=null, defaults=null)>
 at  de.fzj.peerpub.doc.doctype.DocTypeAdminCtrlTest.editPostFormExceptionDTO(DocTypeAdminCtrlTest.java:210)
```

Please note that the properties `mandatory` and `defaults` always get set to `null`, while present in the model. I verified that even my custom validator [DocTypeFormValidator.java](https://github.com/peerpub/peerpub/blob/oliver_dtsvc/src/main/java/de/fzj/peerpub/doc/doctype/DocTypeFormValidator.java) is not seeing this data. This is also causing my `editPostFormSuccess` test to fail: as the properties are set to `null`, the validator is unhappy and the binding result contains errors.

As I unit/integration tested any kind of stuff used by my `DocTypeAdminCtrl.java` I am pretty sure that there must be something missing or wrong either in my controller class or in my test class.

There could be a bug in the `MockMvcRequestBuilderUtils.postForm()` (see [upstream](https://github.com/f-lopes/spring-mvc-test-utils)), but I actually have no clue how to write an alternate `post()` request with my test data containing `Map` and `List`. Having a look at the `MockHttpServletRequestBuilder` with a debugger, all data seems to be present, including `mandatory` and `defaults`, so this might be a less important thing to examine...?

Some suspicious debug log output lines that caught my attention:

```
org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils - No property editor [java.util.MapEditor] found for type java.util.Map according to 'Editor' suffix convention
org.springframework.core.annotation.AnnotationUtils - Failed to meta-introspect annotation interface org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Searching for these errors here on StackOverflow and via Google didn't help much... :-(

**Steps to reproduce:**

Just clone my repo, switch to my feature branch `oliver_dtsvc` and run `mvn test`.

Does anybody out there have a clue? Any help is very much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is entirely related to using `MockMvcRequestBuilderUtils.postForm()` as my helper.

When I manually build a POST request as a proof of concept in `editPostFormSuccess()`, the test runs as expected:

```
ResultActions result = mvc.perform(post("/admin/doctypes/edit/{name}", this.valid.getName())
                                     .param("name", this.valid.getName())
                                     .param("displayName", this.valid.getDisplayName())
                                     .param("system", this.valid.getSystem().toString())
                                     .param("multiDoc", this.valid.getMultiDoc().toString())
                                     .param("attributes[0]", this.valid.getAttributes().get(0))
                                     .param("attributes[1]", this.valid.getAttributes().get(1))
                                     .param("mandatory["+this.valid.getAttributes().get(0)+"]", this.valid.getMandatory().get(this.valid.getAttributes().get(0)).toString())
                                     .param("mandatory["+this.valid.getAttributes().get(1)+"]", this.valid.getMandatory().get(this.valid.getAttributes().get(1)).toString())
                                     .param("defaults["+this.valid.getAttributes().get(0)+"]", this.valid.getDefaults().get(this.valid.getAttributes().get(0)))
                                     .param("defaults["+this.valid.getAttributes().get(1)+"]", this.valid.getDefaults().get(this.valid.getAttributes().get(1)))
);
```

So I will try to figure out how to extend/improve the `MockMvcRequestBuilderUtils`, as it helps a lot in building these requests.
Upstream issue: https://github.com/f-lopes/spring-mvc-test-utils/issues/3